# Select2 not getting data via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have the following code which should be getting data via AJAX using Select2

```
$('#Organisation').select2({
    ajax: {
        url: AppURL + 'Organisations/Manage/SearchByName/',
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 100,
        data: function (term) {
            return {
                term: term
            };
        },
        results: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data
            };
        }
    }
});
```

If I look at the request using Web Inspector when searching 'O' I get:

```
[{"label":"Organisation 1","ID":2},{"label":"Organisation 2","ID":1}]
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'd presume something incorrect in the results function.

The error I get is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toUpperCase' of undefined`

Comment: will you be able to change the json response structure

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try

```
$('#Organisation').select2({
    ajax: {
        url: 'data.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 100,
        data: function (term) {
            return {
                term: term
            };
        },
        results: function (data) {
          var results = [];
          $.each(data, function(index, item){
            results.push({
              id: item.ID,
              text: item.label
            });
          });
          return {
              results: results
          };
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1JdyIqqiZ7GxVQ2tCCgo)

Comment: This is very useful sample. my problem solved after 4 hours searching. thanks

Comment: thank you so much! was very useful for select2.min version 3.5.4 :)

Answer (score 5):

Other than above solution you can do one thing, instead of returning following json

`[{"label":"Organisation 1","ID":2},{"label":"Organisation 2","ID":1}]`

return this

`[{"text":"Organisation 1","id":2},{"text":"Organisation 2","id":1}]`

faced the same problem and figured this out after looking at few solutions proposed by other.