# Populate select2 array of objects via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

**I need to populate a select with a return object arrays**

**CODE**

```
$("#estado").select2({
    placeholder: "Search for a repository",
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
        url: "endpoints/recebeUF.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 250,
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                q: term, 
                page: page 
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
            var more = (page * 30) < data.total_count; 
            return { results: data, more: more };
        }
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; }
});
```

**ARRAY**
[image]

**When I try the popular select2 got the following error:**

*Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined*

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101892/select2-not-getting-data-via-ajax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select2 not getting data via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101892/select2-not-getting-data-via-ajax)